# Node.JS Error with MySQL Database Connection: Terminal is giving me two errors when running my server using the command "NODE INDEX.JS"

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express

I am building a beginner's CRUD application, using JS, Express, CORS, and MYSQL.

What does the application do? (skip this part if you want)

It handles the task of adding employees by their name, age, country, position, and wage and automatically having them inserted into a MySql database.

The way you know if your employee has been added to the system is if you see a "success" statement logged on the console, after you click the "addEmployee" button.

However in my case, I do not see the "success" statement on the console, instead I am met with two errors on my terminal on VsCode:

The errors I am experiencing.

**ERROR #1**

`code: 'ER_NOT_SUPPORTED_AUTH_MODE', errno: 1251, sqlMessage: 'Client does not support authentication protocol requested by server; consider upgrading MySQL client', sqlState: '08004', fatal: true`

**ERROR #2**

`code: 'PROTOCOL_ENQUEUE_AFTER_FATAL_ERROR', fatal: false`

### For Reference Here's my Code:

**----SERVER ----**

**Index.js:**

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const mysql = require("mysql");
const cors = require("cors");


app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());

//Connecting to SQL
const db = mysql.createConnection({
    user: "root",
    host: "localhost",
    password:"password",
    database: "employeeSystem",
});


app.post("/create", (req, res) => {
    const name = req.body.name;
    const age = req.body.age;
    const country = req.body.country;
    const position = req.body.position;
    const wage = req.body.wage;
  

    db.query(
      "INSERT INTO employees (name, age, country, position, wage) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)",
      [name, age, country, position, wage],
      (err, result) => {
          
    
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
        } else {
          res.send("Values Inserted");
        }
      }
    );
  });


app.listen(3001, ()=> 
console.log("You're server is running on port 3001")
)
```

**----CLIENT----**

**App.js:**

```
import "./App.css";
import {useState} from "react"; 
import Axios from "axios";

function App() {
  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  const [age, setAge]= useState(0);
  const [country, setCountry]= useState("");
  const [position, setPosition]= useState("");
  const [wage, setWage] = useState(0);

  const addEmployee = () => {
    Axios.post("http://localhost:3001/create", {
      name: name,
      age: age,
      country: country,
      position: position,
      wage: wage,

  })
  .then(()=> {
    console.log(name, age,country, position, wage);
  })
}
  return (
    <div className="information">
      <div>
      <label>Name:</label> 
      <input 
        type="text"
        onChange={(event)=> {
          setName(event.target.value);
        }}
      />
      <label>Age:</label> 
      <input 
      type="number"
      onChange={(event)=> {
        setAge(event.target.value);
      }}
      ></input>
      <label>Country:</label> 
      <input 
      type="text"
      onChange={(event)=> {
          setCountry(event.target.value);
        }}
      />
      <label>Position:</label> 
      <input 
      type="text"
      onChange={(event)=> {
          setPosition(event.target.value);
        }}
      />
      <label>Wage:</label> 
      <input 
      type="number"
     onChange={(event)=> {
  setWage(event.target.value);
    }}
    />
    <button onClick={addEmployee}> Add Employees</button>
       </div>    
       </div>
       
  );
}

export default App;
```

Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

Try creating a new user for your application on MySQL, instead of using the `root` user. In modern systems `root` is setup to automatically log you in if you use `sudo mysql` and without a password. This is very helpful, for other cases where you just want your program to login *with* a password you get this unhelpful message.

The easiest solution is to just create more mysql users for these cases.

Comment: I am new to mySQL, so i'm a novice when it comes to any database related concepts. How would i be able to add a new mysql user? Can you refactor my code and show me?, Or would it have to be done on MySql workbench?

Comment: Do it in a MySQL client. If your client is workbench, do it there. Maybe there's a GUI, or if not google `CREATE USER`